# $.map jquery acting like a pointer

Tags: jquery

I didn't find a title to qualify that but here is what i don't understand.

let say we create an array using $.map

```
var categoriesTemp = ['a','b','c']
var tempData = $.map(categoriesTemp,function(el,i){
            return 0;
        });
```

After that i assign the temporary table to two different variables

```
var vector1 = tempData;
var vector2 = tempData;
```

What i don't understand is that when i change a value in vector1 it affects vector2 and vice-versa , for example:

```
vector1[1] = 1;
```

The two variables will have the values :

```
Vector1 = [0, 1, 0]
Vector2 = [0, 1, 0]
```

I have read jquery documentation on $.map but didn't found any hint, Can someone explain how is that happening ?

Comment: There is nothing jQuery is doing here, its a normal behavior of how non-primitive objects are passed by reference. So both vector1 and vector2 point to the same variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with jQuery or `$.map` method. This is default behaviour when non-primitive types are passed by reference in Javascript. So since `$.map` returns an object (array-like collection), when you assign it to two variables you basically just assign references to the same object. The same would happen with any other object (or array):

```
var tempData = [1,2,3];

var vector1 = tempData;
var vector2 = tempData;
```

Changes to `vector1` would affect `vector2`.